# Is following code Thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I have a scenario where i have to maintain a Map which can be populated by multiple threads ,each modifying there respective List (unique identifier/key being thread name) and  when the list size for a thread exceeds a fixed batch size we have to persist the records in DB.

Sample code below:

```
private volatile ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<T>>  instrumentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<T>>();
private ReadWriteLock lock ;

public void addAll(List<T> entityList, String threadName) {
    try {
        lock.readLock().lock();
        List<T> instrumentList = instrumentMap.get(threadName);
        if(instrumentList == null) {
            instrumentList = new ArrayList<T>(batchSize);
            instrumentMap.put(threadName, instrumentList);
        }

        if(instrumentList.size() >= batchSize -1){
            instrumentList.addAll(entityList);
            recordSaver.persist(instrumentList); 
            instrumentList.clear();
        } else {
            instrumentList.addAll(entityList);  
        }
    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }

}
```

There is one more separate thread running after every 2 minutes to persist all the records in Map (to make sure we have something persisted after every 2 minutes and map size does not gets too big) and when it starts it block all other threads (check the readLock and writeLock usawhere writeLock has higher priority)

```
if(//Some condition) {
                    Thread.sleep(//2 minutes);
                    aggregator.getLock().writeLock().lock();
                    List<T> instrumentList = instrumentMap .values().stream().flatMap(x->x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                    if(instrumentList.size() > 0) {

                        saver.persist(instrumentList);
                        instrumentMap .values().parallelStream().forEach(x -> x.clear());
                    aggregator.getLock().writeLock().unlock();
                }
```

This solution is working fine almost for every scenario we tested except sometime we see some of the records went missing i.e. not persisted at all although they were added fine in Map

My question is what is the problem with this code? 
Is ConcurrentHashMap not the best solution here?
Does usage of read/write lock has some problem here?
Should i go with sequential processing?

Comment: Hang on, you are persisting things under a *read* lock? Do you think maybe a write lock would be the correct one there?

Comment: If you are using a lock and a concurrent HashMap, you are often do something wrong.

Comment: @Andy Turner whats the problem with read lock when each thread is modifying/persisting its own individual list?

Comment: Whats your suggestion here then? Should i use only write lock ? I cant use Normal HashMap here

Comment: @AndyTurner the solution you suggested is good. But there is one more part of the problem as i mentioned i.e. 'one more separate thread running after every 2 minutes' now this thread is using writeLock which is surely different that atomic operations compute (lock used inside compute).   What do you suggest should i use write lock for both with fairness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not thread safe.

The problem is that you are using the *read* lock of the ReadWriteLock. This doesn't guarantee exclusive access for making updates. You'd need to use the *write* lock for that.

But you don't really need to use a separate lock at all. You can simply use the `ConcurrentHashMap.compute` method:

```
instrumentMap.compute(threadName, (tn, instrumentList) -> {
  if (instrumentList == null) {
    instrumentList = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  if(instrumentList.size() >= batchSize -1) {
    instrumentList.addAll(entityList); 
    recordSaver.persist(instrumentList); 
    instrumentList.clear();
  } else {
    instrumentList.addAll(entityList);
  }

  return instrumentList;
});
```

This allows you to update items in the list whilst also guaranteeing exclusive access to the list for a given key.

I suspect that you could split the `compute` call into `computeIfAbsent` (to add the list if one is not there) and then a `computeIfPresent` (to update/persist the list): the atomicity of these two operations is not necessary here. But there is no real point in splitting them up.

---

Additionally, `instrumentMap` almost certainly shouldn't be volatile. Unless you really want to reassign its value (given this code, I doubt that), remove volatile and make it final.

Similarly, non-final locks are questionable too. If you stick with using a lock, make that final too.

Comment: Thanks for the help i will try this .

Comment: "instrumentList almost certainly shouldn't be volatile" You mean instrumentMap here?

Comment: @Amit yes. Typo.

Comment: Couldn't this code cause problems if the remapping function is called twice? From the Javadoc: "`The default implementation may retry these steps when multiple threads attempt updates including potentially calling the remapping function multiple times.`"

Comment: In fact, calling it in compute doesn't prevent two threads from adding to the same `instrumentList` at the same time.

Comment: @FinnVoichick are you looking at the Javadoc of `ConcurrentMap`, as opposed to `ConcurrentHashMap`?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I didn't realize that `ConcurrentHashMap` overrode the default implementation. But is `ConcurrentHashMap` guaranteed to do this safely?

Comment: @FinnVoichick CHM runs `compute*` atomically.

Comment: @AndyTurner the solution you suggested is good. But there is one more part of the problem as i mentioned i.e. 'one more separate thread running after every 2 minutes' now this thread is using writeLock which is surely different that atomic operations compute.   What do you suggest should i use write lock for both with fairness?